# Problemas con un CURL

Tags: php, curl

modifiqué tal cual me indicas y nada, ¿por qué será?

```
$track='103494';
$url = 'http://s5.stephytrackingonline.com/Cargonam/MainWebsite.asp';


$fields = array(
  'ID'   => $track,
  'Go'   => 1,
  'Type' => 'T'
);

$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

$handler = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($handler ,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($handler ,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($handler ,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

$resultado = curl_exec($handler);

curl_close($handler );

echo $response;
```

Answer (score 1):

Revisando el sitio, te faltan parámetros mediante los cuales hacer el POST.

El form envía varios parámetros ocultos que no estás enviando:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Go" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="Type" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="OpenWindowNoMenuSystemKey" value="">
```

además de procesar mediante JS. Revisando las cabeceras con el inspector de elementos y probando con curl de bash, llegué a que los datos mínimos para que funcione son `ID=<tu tracking>|`, `Type=T` y `Go=1`.

**IMPORTANTE:** se le debe poner si o si un `|` (pipe) al final del tracking o si no, no funciona (fijarse en el caracter escapado `%7C` el que es un |).

```
$ curl -XPOST http://s5.stephytrackingonline.com/Cargonam/MainWebsite.asp -d "ID=104454%7C&Type=T&Go=1" | grep ENTREGADO
```

Retorna:

```
<font face="Verdana" size="1">ENTREGADO</font>
```

Te recomiendo que agregues estos parámetros a tu array `$fields`:

```
$fields = array(
  'ID'   => $track . '|', // <---- se le DEBE poner un | (pipe) al final
  'Go'   => 1,
  'Type' => 'T'
);

// Utiliza http_build_query en vez del foreach + rtrim que estás usando
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
```

Comment: Hola Pablo, gracias por responder, modifique con tus sugerencias y nada: $track='103494';
$url = 'http://s5.stephytrackingonline.com/Cargonam/MainWebsite.asp';


$fields = array(
  'ID'   => $track,
  'Go'   => 1,
  'Type' => 'T'
);

$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

$handler = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($handler ,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($handler ,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($handler ,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

$resultado = curl_exec($handler);

curl_close($handler );

echo $response;

Comment: @JoseDoe ya arreglé el problema ;)